# Fully remove all folders and files on uninstall of Winform app?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, uninstallation

Various files and folders remain after uninstalling my Winform application - including content files (pictures, icons, etc.) and a folder for logs that the application creates.  For the Content files: in the custom installer project, I have the "Permanent" property set to false.  For the logs folder: I assumed this would be deleted with everything else.

Is there a MSI setup property I'm missing or do I need to determine the root path of the Application and remove everything on the overridden `Uninstall` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not. The MSI Installer won't uninstall anything it didn't install, which means that user data, log files, etc. are left.

This is by design - can you imagine the liability if the user mistakenly uninstalled your app and wiped out all their financial data or whatever? Or if they'd mistakenly saved other things to your app's data folder, and your uninstaller deleted them?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It makes sense for the files that I created, but what about the Content Files?  Shouldn't those be deleted?

Comment: If the files were installed by the installer, and they're exactly the same when the uninstall runs, they should be removed, but **only** if both those conditions are true.

Comment: OK - I realized that in the Content Files folder, my application creates another file - which breaks your conditions, above.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See installer keeps information about all those files installed by it and when uninstall gets called, this information tells installer which files or folders to remove. After installation if app or user creates any folder or file, those items remain there after even after uninstallation.

But there is a solution. You can write your own custom action under `OnAfterUninstall` here

```
protected override void OnAfterUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnAfterUninstall(savedState);
    // Write your code
}
```